# Ruby - Using Kernel.exec with custom STDOUT

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to `exec` a shell process such that its standard output is prefixed with an identifier.

My approach is to write a custom `IO` object that re-implements `write`, passing it as the `:out` argument to `exec` (documented under [Process::spawn](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html#method-c-spawn)).

```
require "delegate"

class PrefixedStdout < DelegateClass(IO)
  def initialize(prefix, io) 
    @prefix = prefix
    super(io)
  end 

  def write(str)
    super("#{@prefix}: #{str}")
  end 
end

pr_stdout = PrefixedStdout.new("my_prefix", $stdout)

pr_stdout.write("hello\n")         # outputs "my_prefix: hello"
exec("echo hello", out: pr_stdout) # outputs "hello"
```

Somehow `exec` is bypassing `PrefixedStdout#write` and calling `$stdout.write` directly. How do I force `exec` to use my prefixed output stream as its stdout?

Comment: I don't think this approach can work - what gets passed to your child process is the underlying unix file descriptor. (you could read from that file descriptor, and then write to your desired final output though, adding what prefixes you require)

Comment: Thanks, I guess that makes sense. `pr_stdout.fileno` is 1, which is standard out. Would you mind expanding on your alternative solution a little bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What gets preserved in the other process is the underlying file descriptor (or rather they are hooked up under the hood), so as I commented I don't think you'll ever get writes to that descriptor to be funnelled through your write method - `exec` replaces the running process with a new one.

A possible approach is to create a pipe, pass one end to your child process and then read from the other end, inserting prefixes as needed,

For example you might do

```
IO.pipe do |read_pipe, write_pipe|
  fork do
    exec("echo hello", out: write_pipe)
  end
  write_pipe.close
  while line = read_pipe.gets
    puts "prefix: #{line}"
  end
end
```

You might also be interested in `IO.popen` which wraps some of this up.

Comment: Check your variable names.

Comment: Yeah, it's really obvious why it wasn't working when you put it this way. Thanks for the suggestion, that actually seems like a viable alternative. I was also looking at [Open3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) to allow reading from stdout and stderr independently.

Answer (score 0):

> Somehow exec is bypassing PrefixedStdout#write and calling
>   $stdout.write

Take a look at this example:

```
class MyIO < IO
  def initialize(fd)
    super
  end

  def write(str)
    STDOUT.puts 'write called'
    super
  end
end

fd = IO.sysopen("data.txt", "w")
io = MyIO.new(fd)
io.write "goodbye\n"

puts '---now with exec()...'
exec("echo hello",  :out => io) 

--output:--
write called
---now with exec()...
```

Now, what do you think is in the file data.txt?

spoiler:

> $cat data.txt
>  hello

So passing an IO object to exec() 'works', but not the way you expected:  exec() never calls io.write() to write the output of the child process to io. Instead, I assume exec() obtains the file descriptor for io, then passes it to some C code, which does some system level redirection of the output from the child process to the file `data.txt`.

Do you have to use exec()?  If not:

```
prefix = "prefix: "
cmd = 'echo hello'
output = `#{cmd}`
puts "#{prefix}#{output}"

--output:--
prefix: hello
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't really do it this way because the processes I'm spawning are long-running, so I want to intercept stdout in realtime instead of waiting for the process to complete. I think your reasoning about the way `exec` talks to the `:out` argument is correct though.

Comment: @rickyrickyrice, Okay, then IO.pipe/IO.popen/popen3(et all) will provide the tools you need.